# How to set up a multiboot installation containing two Lubuntu 22.04, the first encrypted, and the second, not encrypted?

Tags: dual-boot, encryption, 22.04, luks

I have the habit to encrypt all the OS that I use because they store sensitive information. However, I would like to share one of my computers, but without providing my encryption phrase. So I thought of a multiboot, with on boot leading to an encrypted OS requiring a passphrase and the other one leading to an OS without passphrase.

Is it feasible? And if so, how to do it?

Comment: you can create one more partition, install lubuntu on it without encryption, and on boot menu you will be able to choose it

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll try that

Comment: I tried that multiple times with gparted, but after that installation inevitably fails.

Comment: do you have any errors for further troubleshooting?

Comment: No, the installation just stops at some point without any error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Prepare a partition for `/boot/efi` and a partition for `/boot` in `gparted`

```
   |------+-------------+-----------+------+-------+-----------|
   | Name | Mount point | Flag      | Size | FS    | Comment   |
   |------+-------------+-----------+------+-------+-----------|
   | sda1 | /boot/efi   | esp, boot | 300M | FAT32 |           |
   | sda2 | /boot       |           | 2G   | EXT4  |           |
   | sda3 |             |           |      | EXT4  | Encrypted |
   | sda4 |             |           |      | EXT4  | Clear     |
   |------+-------------+-----------+------+-------+-----------|
```

2. Install clear GNU/Linux on `sda4`
   At manual partitioning step

   - Select `sda1`

     - Format FAT32
     - Flag esp boot
     - Mount `/boot/efi`
   - Select `sda4`

     - Format EXT4
     - Mount `/`
3. Install crypted GNU/Linux on `sda3`
   At manual paritioning step, *check encrypt*

   - Select `sda1`

     - Mount `/boot/efi`
   - Select `sda2`

     - Format EXT4
     - Mount `/boot`
   - Select `sda3`

     - Delete partition
     - Create partition
     - *Check crypt* and enter passphrase
     - Mount `/`
4. Edit grub

   - From crypted GNU/Linux do `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
   - Enable os-prober by uncommenting `#GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER`false`
   - Do

```
       sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
       reboot
```

Notes

To have the passphrase asked after kernel selection,

- encrypted GNU/Linux kernels have to be stored on a specific `/boot/efi` partition (`sda2`)
- clear GNU/Linux kernels have to be stored in the same partition as clear GNU/Linux (`sda4`)